# How to install Jpcap for Ubuntu

Tags: java, installation, jpcap

This may seem a very stupid question, but I'm facing a lot of trouble with installing jpcap.
I'm new to Ubuntu and unaware of it's architecture, it would be very helpful if you could tell me the process step by step with descriptions.
Presently I'm having the files jpcap-0.7.tar.gz, bison-2.4.1.tar.bz2, m4-1.4.13.tar.gz, flex-2.5.35.tar.gz, libpcap-1.3.0.tar.gz. I read somewhere that these files are required for installing jpcap...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This Is the error i'm getting while executing the file
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jpcap in java.library.path

Comment: This forum is for typical programming problems, if you want to contact CAME facilities help you do better the next: http://serverfault.com/

Comment: The JPCAP documentation seems to tell you what to do, http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/Jpcap/doc/install.html  , and it's likely there's documentation inside jpcap-0.7.tar.gz as well.

Comment: You could also use the Ubuntu StackExchange site: [askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com)

Comment: Thanks for the Reply guyz..
I Had read The Documentation but still Im facing this error

Comment: Solved thanks to all for the reply

Answer (score 3):

Installing from a DEB will be your best bet.

For 32bit edition: http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/Jpcap/jpcap-0.7.deb

For 64bit edition: http://ptcoding.googlecode.com/files/jpcap0.7_amd64.deb

Then if you are using Eclipse IDE, put the jar in /proj/lib folder and add it to the build path.

Comment: Neither of those links exist anymore. Where can I find a 64-bit DEB?

Comment: I had to build from source.