# Installing Jpcap in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, jpcap

I'm trying to install jpcap on ubuntu but it's giving me a bit of bother. I'm using the debian package but when I try to install it it gives me the following error message;

```
Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: sun-java6-jdk
```

I have java 7u9 from oracle as my runtime environment so I assumed that this should work.

Any help would be appreciated!

Here's the [website](https://sites.google.com/site/sipinspectorsite/download/jpcap) with instructions also.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426203/how-to-install-jpcap-for-ubuntu

Comment: also the netresearch.ics.uci.edu link is now down so i can't really use that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Shanee

you can Download from following link.

https://sites.google.com/site/sipinspectorsite/download/jpcap

https://sites.google.com/site/sipinspectorsite/download/jpcap/jpcap-0.7.deb?attredirects=0&d=1
https://sites.google.com/site/sipinspectorsite/download/jpcap/jpcap-0.7.tar.gz?attredirects=0&d=1